# Password automatically typed into user box on facebook

Tags: passwords, facebook, threats, user-names

Just want to ask some questions regarding on this strange experience while logging on my account on Facebook

There are cases that I'm accidentally typing my password into the username box of the Facebook log-in page without knowing it.

I'm gonna demonstrate a detailed sample scenario of logging in a Facebook account. I just used unregistered accounts(I don't want to use my actual account to demonstrate. LOL) for you guys to see and to know well this strange thing that happened to me.

I used a sample but unregistered Facebook account

USERNAME: mike.dnsde23@gmail.com

PASSWORD: thisispassword

First, I type my username on the username box.

[image: First, I type my username on the username box.]

Then I'm about to enter my password

[image: Then I'm about to enter my password]

But before I'm gonna finish typing the password, **THIS IS THE STRANGE THING (that I'm talking about) THAT HAPPENS...**

[image]

As you can see, I've typed almost half of the password to the Password box when it automatically went back on editing the username box causing me to type the other half of the password being seen uncovered .

There are other cases that it automatically went back on editing the username box that I have typed the whole password. It can be considered as a threat especially when usernames are stored according to the browser settings.

My question is Is this a bug thing that Facebook must seriously fix? or is there a problem with my PC or browser settings? or some hacker out there causes this thing automatically acts?

Sorry for the long explanations and some grammatical errors. I hope some geeks out there can explain this spooky thing. thanks a lot!

Comment: I have seen this happen before, and to me, it is a security concern.  I have had this happen on multiple different sites.  I would be very interested to see what is going on here, and have considered asking this question here myself.